# Problems with HHVM and shell_exec

Tags: php, unix, hhvm

I get an error while using `shell_exec()` within a PHP script executed with HHVM:

```
Warning: Unable to execute '/usr/bin/svn update /daniele/myproject' in /daniele/myproject/controllers/evolution.php on line 122
```

The script returns this warning even if executed with root privileges. Does anyone know if there is a problem with the `shell_exec()` in HHVM?

Thanks!

Comment: Any way for you to provide a gist/paste that mimics the code you are trying to run so we can try to reproduce and see what is going on?

Comment: I'm able to run shell_exec in both hack and php in the HHVM.  Does your command throw errors when executed on the command line?

Comment: @joel-marcey In fact I've discovered that shell_exec() gives the warning only when the script has been running for a while (10/15 minutes). Here's an example:

`$command = "nohup nice /usr/bin/hhvm -c config.hdf -vEval.VMStackElms=65536 myphpscript.php &";
shell_exec($command);
exit;`

Comment: @rmcfrazier The command works fine on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced similar issue some times with HHVM 2.2.0. Wasn't able to reproduce it with `sudo su -s /bin/bash hhvm` and it was always gone after hhvm service restart, so it looks like a some kind of leak. Haven't noticed such errors (yet?) after migrating to HHVM 3.1.0 few weeks ago.